# array created from foreach loop now want to insert into database

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I have a form, there i have foreach loop.  I used ajax to get data from the FORM using NAME attr 
for ex: price is coming from a input filed

```
$price = "price$fetch[id]";
<input type="text" id="<?php print $price;?>" name="<?php print $price;?>" value="">
```

This is my array

```
Array (     
    [price26] => 19.07 
    [duration26] => 30 
    [medic_morning26] => 1 
    [medic_day26] => 1 
    [medic_night26] => 1 
    [real_order_qty26] => 
    [order_for_how_many_days26] => 
    [total_price26] => 

    [price27] => 24.22 
    [duration27] => 7 
    [medic_morning27] => 1 
    [medic_day27] => 0 
    [medic_night27] => 0 
    [real_order_qty27] => 
    [order_for_how_many_days27] => 
    [total_price27] => 



    [CUSTOMERID] => 33 
    [prescription_code] => 0001 
    [DA_id] => 
    [given_DA] => errr 
    [new_DA] => 

 )
```

and this is my database filed

```
`price` `duration` `medic_morning` `medic_day` `medic_night` `real_order_qty` `order_for_how_many_days` `total_price`
```

Can anyone help me , to insert the data into database?

Comment: Try to be more specific about what the problem you are having is. Currently your question is too broad. Some suggestions to help clarify for people who want to answer your question: What is the database that you are using? Are you using an ORM to help deal with loading and saving models to the database? What have you already tried doing?

Comment: my problem is , how to insert array data into database when the data coming from a several input box in a foreach loop . For eax: one input box look like this `<input type="number" id="price$fetch[id]" name"price$fetch[id]" value="">` Here you can see i used price with fetch[id] to make the filed unique.

Comment: your input fields should be like that: `<input type="number" id="my_data$fetch[id]" name"my_data$fetch[id][price]" value=""><input type="number" id="my_data$fetch[id]" name"my_data$fetch[id][duration]" value="">` Now you'll be able foreach your id as $key....` foreach ($my_data as $key => $value) { //your stuff here}`

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array_here;  //here your array...
$query = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`price`, `duration`, `medic_morning`, `medic_day`, `medic_night`, `real_order_qty`, `order_for_how_many_days`, `total_price`) VALUES ('$array['price26']', '$array['duration26']', '$array['medic_morning26']', '$array['medic_day26']', '$array['medic_night26']', '$array['real_order_qty26']', '$array['order_for_how_many_days26']', '$array['total_price26']')";

mysqli_query($query);
```

Comment: thanks for answer.. but the key of the array is not fixed (as you can see price26, price27) the price is coming from an input filed <input name="price$fetch['id']" value="" >

Answer (score 0):

my mistake: 
i tried to make all the input filed name unique just like ID , thats why cant manage the name ARRAY ,
so instead of

```
<input name="price$fetch['id']" id="price$fetch['id']" value="" >
```

i used

```
<input id="price$fetch['id']" name="price[]" value="" >
```

now i can handle all the price array (same for other filed..)